# How can I convert this .sh script to a windows executable (.bat)?

Tags: linux, command-line, shell

I created a shell script long back to create a nested directory structure and I now want to use it on my windows machine. Is there an easy way to convert this scripts? Or some quick tips that I should use?

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Enter name of csv file"
read name
echo "Enter the PREFIX for the directory"
read prefix
c=$(echo $prefix | awk -F"/" '{print $NF}')
a=`cat ./$name`
for b in $a
do
mydir=$(echo $b | tr -d '\r' | sed -e 's/,*$//g'| sed -e 's/,/\//g')
mydir2=$(echo $mydir | sed -e 's/\//\/'$c'/g')
mydir1=$prefix$mydir2
mkdir -p $mydir1
echo "Created : `pwd`/$mydir1"
done
```

Comment: Install Cygwin.

Comment: bat files are not executable.  they are just shell scripts, like... well... bash shell scripts.

Comment: @Keltari: But bash shell scripts _are_ executable, just not ELF binary

Comment: Thanks DavidPostill. But I am looking for a long term solution. I will not be able to install Cygwin everywhere and therefore eventually need to convert it to windows executable.

Comment: You should [edit] your question and show the (example) contents of a CSV file and add an explanation how to derive the directories to create from the data in the file and the prefix entered by the user. Your script does basically `for b in $(cat csvfile)`... which should be avoided. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 There might be better options to extract the directory names in a shell script, and you will surely need other mechanisms on Windows. (Maybe this with some "advanced" `FOR` statements.)

Answer (score 4):

The following might serve as a starting point: https://daniel-sc.github.io/bash-shell-to-bat-converter/

Disclaimer: I created this tool. I know it's far from complete. PRs/Help always welcome :)

Comment: it doesn't support functions though :/

Answer (score 2):

There's not really a magical way to convert scripts, except to re-write said scripts manually. That might not always be 100% possible, due to the limitations in the Windows Command Prompt.

However, instead of converting the script, perhaps you could get a windows program that can execute it. If you have Windows 10, you can simply use the new Linux subsystem. There are a million webpages explaining how to do this, so you should be able to find information via a simple websearch.

If you're not running Windows 10, I would recommend a Windows-compatible versions of the Borne Again SHell, and Un*x untilities (specifically `awk`, `cat`, `sed`, and `tr`, since those are what the above script seems to require). MinGW has a good version of both, which you can get (bundled together) from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Installer/mingw-get-setup.exe/download). Run the setup program, and you'll see a window called "MinGW Installation Manager", which will have various packages you can install. "msys-base" should be the only one you need (unless you plan on compiling source code) so put a check mark in the box next to it. Then, go to the "Installation" menu, and select "Apply Changes", and in the window that appears, click "Apply". Assuming you installed MinGW in the default directory (`C:\MinGW`), bash should be located in `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\bash.exe`. You can use this exe file to run your shell scripts.

Answer (score 1):

While your example is pretty easy to convert to BAT, you will fail on Windows' biggest weakness: lack of tools. There's no `tr`, `sed`, `grep`, etc.

Otherwise it's pretty straightforward. `Echo` doesn't need a replacement, `cat` is `type`, while `$` is `%` and so on, but as I said, yours won't work due to the lack of tools in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same needs. Basically, I have a shell script running on my Mac and now I would like to run it by double-clicking on Windows. Here is what I did in Windows 10.

First of all, make sure I can run the .sh through PowerShell given necessary execution policy: open powershell -> dir to the .sh location and run "sh .\shell.sh". Might need to tweak the .sh a little bit.

Secondly, create a one-line .ps1 file: sh "\shell\script\full\path.sh" (" is needed if there is space in the path).

Lastly, create a one-line bat file: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -executionpolicy Bypass -File  "\powershell\script\full\path.ps1"

Comment: Powershell and POSIX Shell are two completely different languages. It's going to be exceedingly rare for any arbitrary script written for one to work in the other. Simply changing the file extension does not magically convert from one language to the other.

Comment: not sure if you read the answer at all. I don't think my answer suggests you can convert a language by simply changing the extension. In this case, you are able to run a shell script in PowerShell by using 'sh' command.

Comment: "I tried to rename my .sh to .ps1" - Sounds like you tried exactly that. Also, the idea of creating a Powershell script wrapper isn't terrible, except that `sh` is not a default part of any version of Windows, and the OP pointed out that they cannot just go about installing new interpreters everywhere.

Comment: I apologize that if the rename statement gives you impression that I am suggesting others do the same thing. On the contrary, I was trying to say not doing that since it doesn't work! Anyway, I removed that. Also, I didn't realize that sh is pretty new to Windows. Thanks for pointing that out. I specified Windows version in my answer. Thanks!

Comment: In terms of `sh` being available for Windows, Cygwin has provided it since 1995, other sources might be even older. In terms of `sh` being *included* with Windows (i.e. does not require installing additional software): this has never been the case. Even the Windows Subsystem for Linux added with the Anniversary Update for Windows 10 is an *additional* install, it is not included by default. Possibly also important: it requires 64-bit desktop Windows. Server SKUs are not supported until the Fall Creator's Update, and 32-bit is not supported at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
set /p name="Entrez le nom du fichier CSV : "
set /p prefix="Entrez le PRÉFIXE pour le répertoire : "

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%b in ("%name%") do (
    set "mydir=%%b"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "mydir=!mydir:~0,-1!"
    set "mydir=!mydir:,=\!"
    set "mydir2=!mydir:/=\%~n1!"
    set "mydir1=%prefix%!mydir2!"
    mkdir "!mydir1!"
    echo Created : %cd%\!mydir1!
    endlocal
)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: A little explanation how this solves the problem presented would make this an answer. You need to give some context and details.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1194882)